# Replacing part of string with another substring in C

Tags: c, string, replace, substring

this code is working perfectly fine in my compiler(DEV C++) but not in Ideone.com . It is not accepting replacement string. is there anything wrong with my logic ? May I know whats wrong with my code?

```
//splitting a string and replace latter part of string by another string
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int i,count=0,loc2=0,scount=0,rcount=0,loc=0;       //scount represents counter for substring and rcount for replacement and loc from where we will split the string
char str[100],sub[100],newss[100];  //newss=new substr, rslt and rslt2=former and latter part of original string
int main()
{
    String();
    substring();
    new_string();
    concat();
    return 0;
}
void String()
{
    printf("Enter a String:\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("\nString Entered by User:\n");
    puts(str);
    printf("\nLoc Char\n");         //Creates Colums 'Char' and 'Loc'
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        count++;                                //Counts length of String
        printf("%d. %c\n",count,str[i]);    //Prints Characters with it its Corresponding Location
    }
    printf("\n\nLength of String: %d\n\n",count);
}
void substring()
{
    printf("Enter the locations of Characters from where substring will start and end: \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&loc,&loc2);       //stores indices of begining and end of substring
    printf("\n\nSubset formed from Existing String:\n");
    for(i=loc-1;i<loc2;i++)
    {
        scount++;
        sub[i]=str[i];              //stores substring in "sub"
        printf("%c",sub[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nLength of substring: %d\n",scount);
}
void new_string()
{
    printf("\n\nEnter a Replacement for substring(Of Equal Length as that of substring):\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(newss);
    for(i=0;newss[i]!='\0';i++)
    rcount++;
    printf("\n\nLength of New substring: %d\n",rcount); //-1 to subtract length of null char
}
void concat()
{
    if(rcount!=scount)      //to check whether replacement string and substring are of same length
    printf("\nSince length of both substrings is not same. \nHence Replacement is Not Possible\n");
    else        //Concatination of 3 substrings
    {
        printf("\nResultant String:\n");
        for(i=0;i<(loc-1);i++)
        printf("%c",str[i]);
        for(i=0;newss[i]!='\0';i++)
        printf("%c",newss[i]);
        for(i=loc2;str[i]!='\0';i++)
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... nothing but global variables, that's something you don't see every day. Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code and see what's wrong?

Comment: put prototype `void String(void);
void substring(void);
void new_string(void);
void concat(void);
` before `main()`

Comment: @Mike and Bluepixy this is my ideone link... http://ideone.com/qREVVI
I've tried everything but its not working. but the surprizing fact it is working perfectly fine in all compilers except ideone!

Comment: it is rewritten so that it does not use the `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: @Bob - It doesn't matter if it's "working perfectly fine" in most compilers, you're relying on something that's not defined in the C standard, and the fact is you ***haven't*** tried everything. Replace your `gets()` [call with the `scanf()` using the negated scanset and you'll see it working](http://ideone.com/QRRGBc).

Comment: @Mike I tried scanf too but it won't accept more than 1 word!

Comment: @Bob - *negated scan set*. Not `" %s"` this: `" %[^\n]"`, I updated the link in my previous comment so you can **see** it working in ideone. I hightly recommend reading [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) it will help you understand how these functions work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a number of strange things, and some bad things as well, one of the big problems is you're intermixing calls to `gets()` and `scanf()`, they handle new line characters differently and it's getting you in trouble.

When you call `substring()` it's using `scanf()` to get the two substring indexes, but it's leaving a newline character(`'\n'`) on `stdin`, then your call to `gets()` is reading that and using it as the string.

Change:

```
gets(newss);
```

To:

```
scanf(" %s", newss);
```

And things will work in ideone.com.

You maybe wondering why did you have this problem when you called `fflush(stdin);` just before reading `newss`. This is part of what I described as "bad things" before. `fflush(stdin)` should NEVER be done. This leads to undefined behavior, `fflush()` is well defined for `stdout` but not for `stdin`. This means calling it *could* flush the input buffer or it could not it depends on how that was implemented in the IDE you were using (or if it was at all). If it's not defined in the C standard, you can't assume it will work.

---

EDIT:
your example is using spaces in the substring you're entering so the answer is the same, but you need to use the negated scanset:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", newss);   // note my examples start with a blank space
//     ^
//     |
//   here
```

The blank space will tell `scanf()` to ignore any remaining "white space" characters left on `stdin`, that means that left over `'\n'` will not be considered. However that ALSO means that if your replacement string starts with a space that space will be ignored. You can read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for `scanf()` and consider exactly what you want to use for your input string based on your assignment requirements.

Comment: it working when I used scanf(" %[^\n]", newss);
but may I know what was wrong when I was using gets or fgets?

Comment: Note : it may begin with a space string to try to replace.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - True... but since we *don't know* what the exact assignment requirements are for the "substring" we can't provide an answer that accounts for everything. I mean it could be acceptable that the "substring" is just a newline and nothing else. I'm not going to provide a solution for every possible thing I can think of, just an explanation of what's happening and a possible fix, I leave it to the OP to fine tune to the needs of the assignment.

Comment: @Bob - I actually did tell you why it wasn't working before. The problem is when you intermix `fgets()` and `scanf()` calls you have to be very careful with how you handle those leftover newlines. In your case your `scanf()` left a newline and your `gets()` read that as input. `flush(stdin)` is not defined by the C standards so that means you can't use that to clear the input buffer (it might work some times, some place, but there's no guarantee.